# Detecting mouse clicks in python Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse

Is there a way to detect when the mouse is clicked on a Tkinter canvas in python, only using modules which are downloaded with the python package?

Comment: I don't have pygame.

Comment: Just about any tkinter tutorial will show you how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess a possible answer would be

```
root = Tk()
canvas= Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
canvas.bind("<Key>", key)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack()
```

Where key and callback are functions you have to define yourself.
From [How to bind a click event to a Canvas in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211794/how-to-bind-a-click-event-to-a-canvas-in-tkinter)