# How do we call itterative function in tkinter - Python-?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to tkinter, and I would like to start a kind of loop, from the moment I pressed a key on my keyboard.
Only, when I call my first function, I have an error:

TypeError: anime_avancer () missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'.

I understand that there is something to do with the bind method, but I do not understand the structure ...
Thank you in advance !

```
from tkinter import *

fen=Tk()
can=Canvas(fen,bg="light gray", height=500, width=500)
can.pack()

def afficher_codeur():
    #code here
    anime_avancer()

def anime_avancer(event):
    #code here#
    afficher_codeur()

fen.bind("<Right>", anime_avancer)

fen.mainloop()
```

I would like to have explanations on the role of the "event" if possible, thanks ! ;)

Comment: Your `anime_avancer` callback has a call to `afficher_codeur` that calls itself `anime_avancer` again, but with no arguments instead of one. What did you expect du cul?

Comment: So what am I supposed to put in (le cul) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `anime_avancer` callback has a call to `afficher_codeur` that calls itself `anime_avancer` again, but with no arguments instead of one. Hence the runtime error.

If you want at some point to call your `anime_avancer` method but without any argument, simply call `anime_avancer(None)`.

`event` in a Tkinter canvas callback is a positional argument that stores various informations about the state of your keyboard & mouse when the event is fired. For instance, `event.x` and `event.y` store the position of your mouse.

See the complete documentation for `Canvas.bind()` [here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html).

A complete example on how to use a callback method in Tk is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211794/how-to-bind-a-click-event-to-a-canvas-in-tkinter).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Antoine C, the answer was to put "None" as an argument of the anime_avancer function in the afficher_codeur loop!