# How to make a shape a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, graphics

Is there a way to make a shape a button in a tkinter canvas?

```
 button = Canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200)
```

Or, to put it simply, is there a way to figure out if the user clicked the rectangle drawn above?

Comment: Seems to be already asked question. here you go - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211794/how-to-bind-a-click-event-to-a-canvas-in-tkinter

Comment: Use `canvas.tag_bind(button, '<Button-1>', callback)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to see if someone clicks the rectangle but you could have the color change if a cursor hovers over it...

I'm going to make the rectangle red, and then it will turn blue with a cursor hovering over...

```
button = Canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200, fill = 'red', activefill = 'blue')
```

this might not be exactly what you are looking for, but it is another option...

also if u just want a button:

```
from tkinter import *

def say_hello():
    print("Hello")

root = Tk()
btn1 = Button(root, text="Hello", command=say_hello)
btn1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

when pressed it will print hello!

Comment: @quantalabs would appreciate an upvote :)