# Python canvas mouse events

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop

I found a lot of questions about canvas mouse events but nothing with python

so my question is: how do I use mouse events in python canvas

If this question is quite weard, this is my first question on stack overflow

Comment: I assume you're talking about Python tkinter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211794/how-to-bind-a-click-event-to-a-canvas-in-tkinter

Comment: yes, I am talking about tkinter

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm for an introduction on events binding.

A canvas is a `widget` so you can bind mouse events to it like:

```
def on_left_button_clicked(event):
   # retrieve mouse properties eg coordinates from the event


c = tk.Canvas(root,....)
c.grid(...) # or pack
c.bind("<Button-1>", on_left_button_clicked)
```

Contrary to other widgets, the canvas provides helper function to related mouse coordinates to canvas ones (because the canvas can be "dragged"). See here for canvas specificities:

http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

or:

https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

Comment: Link down. Mirror: https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/