# How do you register a mouseclick on a Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, thonny

I'm currently trying to make a Tkinter ISPY game in thonny, I found out that I can't use buttons on as they are too obvious. If anyone knows what phrase I would use to research how to register a mouseclick on a canvas (it would have to be a range/ general area of where the image is). I am very much so a beginner so if you know what I'm talking about please dumb-down your answer so I can understand.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind a click event to a Canvas in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211794/how-to-bind-a-click-event-to-a-canvas-in-tkinter)

Comment: @Atlas435, Thank you for the response. This does help, however, I am still not sure how to assign event.x or event.y to a variable. If you know please let me know.  Thank you for your response, it was extremely helpful. :)

Comment: `x, y = event.x, event.y`